# Data from one html to another in JSON jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Looked through the topics but found no full answer.

My task is to fill a drop-down with text from another HTML file. Both HTML files are on localhost. Having data in JSON is a requirement.

Initially, came into following:

```
$.getJSON("feed.html", function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (index, item) {
            $('#insider').append($('<option</option>').val(item).html(item));
        });
    });
```

Although, this does not seems to work as `getJSON` does not seem to operate with `html` but `.json` files instead.

Problem is second file has to remain in `.html` format. Are there any other possibilities how to have whole `html` text inserted as `json` without having separate `.json` file?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to get HTML into JSON and into HTML again without having any server side script doing this. What you want to do is make an AJAX request for a HTML file, extract the data you need and then insert that data into the current HTML file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jQuery.ajax` with the `json` `dataType` parameter:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "feed.html",
    dataType: "json",
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

And in feed.html:

```
[{"hello":"world"}]
```

This will return a JSON object as the data value in the `.done` callback. So with your code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "feed.html",
    dataType: "json",
}).done(function(data) {
    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
        $('#insider').append($('<option</option>').val(item).html(item));
    });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, above appended none. `Html` I am querying to contains of usual text in `p` and `h#` tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

```
$.get( "feed.html", function( data ) {
   var parsedHtml = [];

   // parse/split the html up here and push it onto the array
   ....

   $.each(parsedHtml , function (index, item) {
      $('#insider').append($('<option</option>').val(item).html(item));
   });
});
```